# I am Getting the error undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a super simple newsletter application, and I'm confused about this error. Why is there a `nil` class? I am only asking it to render, so why cant I put a `redirect_to` where the `render` call is?.

```
 <% if admin_signed_in? %>

   <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

   <h1>Subscribedusers</h1>

   <table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<% @subscribedusers.each do |subscribeduser| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= subscribeduser.email %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', subscribeduser %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_subscribeduser_path(subscribeduser) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', subscribeduser, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Subscribeduser', new_subscribeduser_path %>

<% else %>

<%= render '/' %>

<% end %>
```

Why does this part of the code `<%= render '/' %>` trigger an `undefined method 'empty?' for nil:NilClass` error?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `render '/'`?

Comment: i want it to return to the homepage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your desire is to return the user to the home page, instead of

```
render '/'
```

you should use

```
redirect_to root_path
```

The difference is `render` prepares the output to be displayed as the result of the **current** request and `redirect_to` commands user's browser to make a **new** request at specified url.

While it can be possible to render the contents of your home page in an arbitrary action, this is rarely desirable. One downside is the page url would not automatically update to your site's root in the browser's address line.

As a side note, `render '/'` is not a correct syntax. `render` [generally accepts](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render) a hash of options and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have an <% else %> clause without any conditional loops? And what are you trying to call with <% render '/' %>? Are you trying to call the index page? If so, you can specify by saying <% render "index" %> .

Comment: Sorry, there is an if condition, i did not include it in the code properly, still get the same error though

Answer (score 0):

So you don't need if and else block in view side for page redirect to root path.
From your controller's whatever action you need following code.

if admin_signed_in?
     redirect_to root_path
end

also remove if and else block from view.